# Altium duplicate Silkscreen between projects

Tags: altium, silkscreen

I have one project on Altium in 2 different versions (version control is out of the scope of this question). I worked on the silkscreen in one version (let's say v1) and I would like to update the v2 with the silkscreen. The components did not move, only the designators moved.

I am able to select all the designators to copy, but when pasting, nothing happens. How can I duplicate the silkscreen of v1 to v2?

Comment: `I am able to select all the designators to copy, but when pasting, nothing happens.` That's probably Altium does not allow you to copy a part of a component (e.g. designator) but the entire component.

Comment: What did the many Altium forums advise was the answer (before you came to this site)?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not manage to find any relevant answer. Looked "how to copy/duplicate/export single layer" "Duplicate designators PCB" and so much more...

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).